# Prove that $f(x)\le \text{esssup} f\quad\text{a.e}\quad \text{in}\quad X $: What happens when $\text{esssup} f =-\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f\colon X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a measurable function we define:

$$\text{esssup} f=\inf\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; f(x)\le \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$

I must prove that $$f(x)\le \text{esssup} f\quad\text{a.e}\quad \text{in}\quad X \tag1$$

**My solution.**

If $\text{esssup}=+\infty$, then $(1)$ holds. We suppose that $M:=\text{esssup} f\in\mathbb{R}$, then for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ exists $\alpha_k\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\le \alpha_k$ a.e. in $X$ such that $M+\frac{1}{k}>\alpha_k$. So, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ exists a $\mu$-null set $N_k$ such that $f(x)<M+\frac{1}{k}$ for all $x\in X\setminus N_k:=N_k^c$.

We define $N:=\cup N_k$, then $N$ is a $\mu$-null set and we have $$f(x)<M+\frac{1}{k}\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\forall x\in N^c,$$ therefore $f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in N^c$. $(N^c:=X\setminus N).$

> What happens when $\text{esssup} f =-\infty$?

Comment: In that case, $f=-\infty$ a.e..

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks, so it is right state that $$\text{esssup}f=-\infty \implies f=-\infty\quad\text{a.e}\; \text{in}\; X?$$